# how to add ironic db version file. now install don't copying db version file. how to do?

Tags: database, migration, version, openstack, alembic

please allow me ask question. very very thank you.

I want to add a db version into ironic, the version in "ironic /db/sqlalchemy/alembic/version/"
The db version file name I user ironic-dbsync generate version file name

First:  I use ironic-dbsyncto generate this db version number and file name

[image: Inline image 3]

Second: write the file then put the file into ironic/db/sqlalchemy/alembic/versions/" path
[image: Inline image 2]

Third: python setup.py build. run bunild but I cant't see my version file "24ed1d92a2d_add_user_nodes_table.py" , why ?
[image]

I want add a db version file. can tell me how to do ?   very very thank you !!!

Comment: machine environment problems , and ironic has nothing to do , I asked wrong, sorry

Answer (score 0):

We have this item [covered in our FAQ](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/ironic/dev/faq.html#create-a-migration-script-template). By following it, you'll get an empty template which you can then populate. As an alternative, you can autogenerate your database migration file. There are a few examples in the [ironic-inspector documentation](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/ironic-inspector/contributing.html#making-changes-to-the-database), the process must be very close for ironic.

Hope that helps.